# how to do a jquery glass calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, calculator

I am getting ready to star dealing with a jquery price calculator for glasses. One box is going to have width, another box height, a dropdown is going to have type of glass. 
Another box quantity
I have to calculate the price of the glass.
I have the calculator working, my question is the following, how can I update the .showResults class? this is the place where I will show the results but I would this to be updated as soon as the user selects a dropdown, then puts width or height? can this be done?

Thank you :)
here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 
$("#calculate").click(function(){
 
 var typeOfGlass=$("select#typeOfGlass option:selected").val();
 var glassWidth = $("#glassWidth").val();
 var glassHeight = $("#glassHeight").val();
 var quantity = $("#quantity").val();
 if(!(quantity) || quantity == ''){
  alert("Quantity cannot be 0, please correct"); 
 }
 var sqrFt = typeOfGlass/144;
 var price = 2;
 if(glassWidth<10 || glassHeight<10){
  var totalPrice = 10 * quantity; 
 }else{
 var totalPrice = glassWidth * glassHeight * sqrFt * quantity;
 }
 $(".showResults").empty();
    $(".showResults").append("<p>The total price is: $" +totalPrice.toFixed(2));
});
})
</script>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
 <select id="typeOfGlass">
   <option value="15">Standard/Annealed Glass</option>
     <option value="20">Tempered Glass</option>
    </select><br>

 Glass Width:<input type="text" id="glassWidth"><br>

    Glass height:<input type="text" id="glassHeight"><br>

    Quantity:<input type="text" id="quantity"><br>

  <input type="button" name="calculate" id="calculate" value="Calculate"><input type="reset" value="Clear" />
</form>
```

Comment: Nobody can teach you how to build pricing calculators in a simple answer here.

Comment: Adding a vote to close as off topic / asking for help without showing work already done. Now, that said, please go Google `jquery calculator tutorial`. I'm sure there are many things that can hep you. SO is happy to help you when you get stuck, but, unfortunately, we don't provide free end-to-end coding :)

Comment: Thank you guys, I do not want to offend anybody, I am just new to stack overflow and I just started with this new project. In the immediate future I will post sample code, and also I am already using google and jquery.com. Thanks again.